# Am I exceeding maximum ratings for the power rails of the opamp?

Tags: operational-amplifier

[This  Dual Rail-to-Rail opamp](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lmc6482.pdf) :

I implemented a circuit with this dual rail-to-rail opamp on a breadboard and used a ±15V dual supply. The outputs saturate either to negative or positive rail which I'm not expecting as outputs. In simulation everything works fine but in real I checked the wirings ten times I couldn't find the problem.

My question is regarding the following absolute max ratings for the power rails:
[image]

Does 16V above mean that the max supply rail for the opamp is

Vcc<16 and |Vee|<16V?

As I mentioned I use +15V for Vcc and -15V for the Vee. Am I exceeding limits?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep, you're exceeding them. Notice how it says

> Supply voltage (V+ - V-)    MAX: 16V

this means that the total voltage difference between V+ and V- cannot exceed 16V, whereas your supply of +/-15V has a total difference of 30V. Time to buy a new op amp.

Comment: It is exposed to this 30V differential voltage one hour:(

Comment: Time exposed is irrelevant.  Once you break datasheet specifications, operation (or lack thereof) is undefined.

Comment: Indeed, especially if you exceed it by 15V.